# An error appear when I use "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" in SSMS v.17.1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with the version v.17.1 of the SQL Server Management Studio. And theoretically, the query `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` works from SQL Server 2016.

You can see this in the official web page of Microsoft: [DROP TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql)

However, when I try to execute the query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.EmpLocations;
```

an error appears:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

What is the problem? I'm using a specific database of Microsoft to work with SQL Server 2016 - 2017.

Comment: What SQL Server **database engine** are you running against? Run `SELECT @@VERSION` to confirm....

Comment: @Pரதீப் Why did you kill your answer; it looks right to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Nope it is wrong.. OP knows it will work only from `SQL SERVER 2016`.. He/She is thinking engine is `SQL SERVER 2016` but they may be using `SSMS 2016` and database engine might less than 2016. As mentioned by Marc `@@VERSION` will help to understand the issue

Comment: OK...but still a technicality; you correctly pointed out that `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` is version dependent.  That's worth at least an upvote IMO.

Comment: The version of management studio is irrelevant. The commands are executed by the server so it is the server that needs to be SQL Server 2016+

Comment: Is the Compatibility Level of the database set to some older version than 2016?

Comment: Exactly. I didn't know that. 
I am using the SQL Server Management Studio v17.1. However, when I use SELECT @@VERSION, appears that I am using SQL Server 2014

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)   Jun 10 2015 03:35:45   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 15063: )

Comment: When I go to the table properties-->options-->Compatibility level, doesn't appear SQL Server 2016 (only 2008,2012,2014).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, It was my mistake :(

As other people have said, I was using the SQL Server Management v.17.1; however, I was working yet with the version of SQL SERVER 2014.
I began to install the new SQL 2016, but I only installed the SSMS17, and not the SQL Server 2016 itself.

Now, I have installed correctly the version of SQL SERVER 2016. And I can execute the query `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sales.Orders2;` without any problem!

If I go to the version (`SELECT @@VERSION`), I can see that I have the correct installed: *Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64)   Jul  6 2017 07:55:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 6.3  (Build 15063: )*

And remember that the new version of SQL2016 they have introduced this new way to drop tables https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/

Answer (score 19):

for backwards compatibility with all versions of sql-server, use this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.emplocations') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.emplocations;
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

We have many ways to do this but generally it's not a practice to `DROP` and `CREATE` the physical tables you can use temporary tables instead

Check Existence of real table and DROP:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where name = 'myTable' AND type = 'U')
    DROP TABLE dbo.myTable

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.myTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.myTable;
```

Check existence of temporary table and DROP:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#myTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #myTable;
```

Comment: SQL Server **2016** introduced the `IF EXISTS` keyword - so **YES**, this **IS** valid SQL Server (2016+) syntax: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS .....`

Comment: And the syntax was introduced because it has a valid use case - dropping tables in deployment scripts. The suggestion of using temp tables is completely irrelevant to this.

Comment: Thanks for updating, the line is removed now, sorry as I was unaware of it.

Comment: how to do to drop and create in one shot with ADO.net

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012, the `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where ...)` check worked for me.  But, the `IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.myTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL` did not work;  I got a syntax error at the NULL.